# Dialog error after killing activity in Android application

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, dialog

I'm in Activity example.activity.SetupManage. After some operations I call a dialog that shows a notification message. But even if I don't click OK button, all the subsequent code is executed, so when I kill all Activity the dialog creates problems. What can I do for solving my problem?

```
    AlertDialog myAlertDialog;
    public void onDestroy(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    if(myAlertDialog.isShowing())
        myAlertDialog.dismiss();
}
  // *** some operations *** //
  try{
        myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Notification")
        .setMessage("Operation Failed")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    })
    .show();

    }
    catch(Exception ex){

    }

    try{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent();
    myIntent.setClassName("example.activity", "example.activity.MainActivity");
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    }catch(Exception ex){

    }
```

Error message:

```
   10-16 15:33:11.120: E/WindowManager(4360): Activity example.activity.SetupManage has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@415ca638 that was originally added here
   10-16 15:33:11.120: E/WindowManager(4360):   at example.activity.SetupManage.CleanDatabase(SetupManage.java:61)
   10-16 15:33:11.120: E/WindowManager(4360):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:288)
   10-16 15:33:11.120: E/WindowManager(4360):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:249)
   10-16 15:33:11.120: E/WindowManager(4360):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
   10-16 15:33:11.120: E/WindowManager(4360):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
   10-16 15:33:11.120: E/WindowManager(4360):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:532)
   10-16 15:33:11.120: E/WindowManager(4360):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:269)
   10-16 15:33:11.120: E/WindowManager(4360):   at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:907)
   10-16 15:33:11.120: E/WindowManager(4360):   at example.activity.SetupManage.CleanDatabase(SetupManage.java:61)
```

Comment: You show a dialog then change the activity, you need to dismiss the dialog first

Answer (score 2):

It continues to execute because that's what you're telling it to do. If you want code to execute when you dismiss the dialog, put it in the `onClick` of the dialog buttons, or `onDismiss` if available.

More to the point, why is any of this in `onDestroy()` in the first place? It seems like a very bad place to put a dialog(or an intent calling another activity 99.8% of the time). You'll never be able to see it, the activity is being destroyed *right now*. I'd recommend rethinking the flow of your program.

Answer (score 1):

```
Replace this code , it can help you...pass getApplication context 

 try{
        myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext() )
        .setTitle("Notification")
        .setMessage("Operation Failed")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    })
    .show();

    }
    catch(Exception ex){

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the AlertDialog to a variable:

myAlertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).....

and in the onPause() method, if the dialog is active, you should dismiss it!

Comment: Right! Can I have the same result calling the dismiss method from onDestroy?